# $T$ is an isomorphism if and only if there are $c,k>0$ such that $c||x|| \leq ||T(x)|| \leq k||x||$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, continuity, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $T : E \longrightarrow F$ a linear bijective operator between normed spaces, then $T$ is an isomorphism if and only if there are $c,k>0$ such that
$$c||x|| \leq ||T(x)|| \leq k||x||,$$
for all $x \in E$.

My attempt was:

$(\Leftarrow)$ If there is $k>0$ such that $||T(x)||\leq k||x||$, then $T$ is continuous. So, by the fact that $T\in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ and exists $c>0$ such that $||T(x)||\geq c||x||$, for all $x\in E$, then the inverse operator $T^{-1}$ exists and it's continuous. So, $T$ is an isomorphism, since $T$ is already bijective.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Supose that $T$ is an isomorphism. So $T$ is continuous and bijective. Thus exists $k>0$ such that $||T(x)||\leq k||x||$, for all $x\in E$.

BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PROCEED.

I think the first inequality is given from the continuity of $T^{-1}$, but I don't know how to do it. Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: The continuity of $T^{-1}$ gives you $||T^{-1}(T(x))||\leq L||T(x)||$, for all $x\in E$.

Comment: @PQH Thanks! I just realized it before your answer. But you confirmed my idea.